# How to run code before Chrome app has been uninstalled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

From the [chrome docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) I can see that one can subscribe to an 'installed' and 'updated' events using the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener function(){
    // do something when the app is installed
}
```

My question is: Is there some when to subscribe to the event where the user decides to uninstall the app? i.e. something like:

```
chrome.runtime.onUninstall.addListener function(){
    // do something when the app is installed
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best option is this:

`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(string url)`

> Sets the URL to be visited upon uninstallation. This may be used to clean up server-side data, do analytics, and implement surveys. Maximum 255 characters.